# Logic issue with changing a variable in PHP

Tags: php, sql, logic

I'm a total noob when it comes to PHP, as I'm sure you'll discover once you read this question.

I'm messing around and trying to learn, and I've made a chat room using PHP. I'm trying to add functionality so that a user can change which room they are in by using a drop-down box with some pre-defined rooms. I have a login page which asks for a username, password, and which room (the dropdown box). The login page then directs to the index.php page which is where the rest of the chat code is at. The index page has a section that checks to see if the user has changed rooms. If they have changed, it displays a message in the OLD room to say that they've left, and a welcome message in the NEW room.

The issue that I've run into is that when I log in, the room variable gets broken somehow. It puts me in a "blank" room. If I use the drop down box after that to change rooms, everything works fine. I'm just having issues with the initial login.

I tried removing the change room "routine" completely, and I'm able to log in just fine (but I can't switch rooms, obviously) -- so that leads me to believe that there's a logic error somewhere here.

Sorry for the long-winded description - I'm new here and I don't know how much info to provide.

Here's the code that I have that checks/changes rooms -- anyone have any recommendations?

```
    //check for room change
if(!($_SESSION['room'] == $_POST[r])){
$query = "INSERT INTO roomdata (message, room) VALUES (' * $_SESSION[username] ($flags$ip$flags) has joined the room. Welcome!!', '$_POST[r]'), ('* $_SESSION[username] has left the room.','$_SESSION[room]')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$_SESSION['room'] = $_POST['r'];
}
```

Again, I'm new to PHP and I'm sure my code is pretty crappy. I'm also aware that mysql is depreciated, but I'm just doing this for a hobby and I'll learn mysqli once I've got this sorted out.

Thank you in advance to anyone who has time to help!

Comment: Before last paragraph; yeah... I'm afraid so (*well, you said it*). `$_POST[r]` missing quotes `[r]` is being treated as a constant. Make sure you've started the session... *hm....* what else...  ah yes... major sql injection.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: When you log in what kind of operations do you do related to the session?

Comment: once the login form is submitted and the username/pass is verified, it does:
`$room = $_SESSION['room'];
$nickname = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "INSERT INTO roomdata (message, room) VALUES (' *** $nickname ($flags$ip$flags) has joined the room. Welcome!!',$room ')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
 header('Location: index.php');`

Comment: @ Fred -- It's pretty bad, I know. I may just scrap it all and try to learn the new stuff. I just thought I'd check before I started over completely. I appreciate the honesty.

Comment: Using prepared statements will definitely be an asset Mike. Plus, escaping your inputs will also prove beneficial, so you may as well jump into that right away. Plus, use error checking and reporting, and `var_dump();` which will help you along the way; cheers.

Comment: Do you recommend PDO or msqli? I'm not really sure where to start, honestly. I've not messed with any of this in ages (obviously) -- just trying to do it for a hobby and learn something along the way.

Comment: Either one is good. I use both myself and never constrict myself to one. It keeps me sharp ;-) Also, I tend to think that, if I don't use one for the longest time, I'll tend to forget. But the "prepared" method is what to use. `mysqli` or PDO on its own doesn't safeguard against injection.

Comment: well, back to the drawing board I guess.. lol. I appreciate your time and information. 

I don't suppose you could recommend any nice tutorials for this type of thing?

Comment: My pleasure Mike. There's http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059 and http://markonphp.com/insert-pdo-prepared-statement/ and the manuals http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements and http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and a whole bunch of links under my profile, related to MySQL - SQL.

Comment: I just wanted to come back and thank you again, @Fred-ii-  . I've found an excellent tutorial on PDO and OOP php. I can see how why it is SO much better than the way I was doing things before. Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: That's very nice of you Mike, thanks and you're very much welcome, *cheers!*